# Isn't asking for the price of the Selenium program equivalent to promote a product or service as per Stack Overflow standards?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spam, moderator-intervention

Isn't asking for the price of the Selenium program equivalent to promote a product or service as per Stack Overflow standards?

The discussion have a reference to the question [Price of the Selenium program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556598/price-of-the-selenium-program) where OP clearly asked the Stack Overflow volunteers to *find out an approximate price for his work*.

In my opinion, asking for *Price of the Selenium program* is equivalent to *promote a product or service* and I have marked it as `spam` against the clause *Exists only to promote a product or service*. However it seems it didn't go well with the lawmakers and was *declined*.

Can anyone guide me if *asking for Price of the Selenium program* suits as a valid question?

---

<sub>Users under 10k may have views to contribute:</sub>

[image: SO51556598 deleted Q]

Comment: No, that's not a question that is on topic here. That does not make it *spam* however.

Comment: Hard to say. These types of questions *can* be thinly disguised spam, but this can often be difficult to suss out. This particular question doesn't seem suspicious, though, other than the unfortunately spammy-looking links.

Comment: That post does not read like a promotion. To me, that post is asking a genuine, good faith question and their only mistake is not understanding that such posts are off-topic here. Note: **nowhere are they linking to their output**, the only links are for a screenshot and for booking.com links.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have emphasized on the word  **promote a product or service** while considering it spam as per the clauses available for _flagging_. Was that a wrong decision?

Comment: @pnuts But... it doesn't link to the product, or mention its name, or provide any information that would let you find it if you wanted it. How can it possibly be promoting something that it doesn't name or provide a mechanism for you to buy?

Comment: @MarkAmery Rather than _product_ isn't it promoting a _service_?

Comment: @DebanjanB: What service is it promoting? Can you tell from the post?

Comment: @pnuts: with that definition you can flag a whole lot more posts on SO as spam. A genuine, good faith attempt at a question can very often include a description of a service or product being worked on, yet is *not spam*. Please don't stretch definitions.

Comment: @pnuts Our definition of spam here, written in the flag description, is that the post **Exists only to** promote a product or service. That is to say: we explicitly define spam in terms of the poster's intentions. Of course that's a definition that occasionally requires some judgement (since we cannot read minds, and so must try to infer intentions as best we can), but it sounds like you're trying to judge this stuff without considering intent at all, and that's at odds with the flag description.

Comment: @pnuts I guess that - the point about definitions aside - I don't see in what way this post is "unintentionally" "advertising" the software being talked about any more than, say, a typical crap website-debugging question that links to the site in question is "unintentionally" "advertising" it - and we don't spam flag those. Is your take that asking for prices is sort-of-equivalent to soliciting buyers, and that this makes it more spammy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case Martijn has explained why the moderators reviewing this post think that it's fairly clear that the post was in fact asked in good faith, and that it was not spam masquerading as a programming question.

But there *are* unscrupulous users that go around asking questions that are designed to look, on a surface level, like they're someone not affiliated with the product asking an actual programming question, when in fact they *are* affiliated with the product and are just using the "question" as an excuse to get the name of their product out there or to throw in some links for SEO juice.

If you come across one of these cases, where you think someone is really trying to be sneaky, and isn't actually asking their question in good faith, it's probably worth a custom mod flag.  There are two reasons here.  First, if you think this, you probably want to include more information in your flag than just "this is spam".  You're going to want to add why you think they're affiliated with the product (perhaps their name or something on their profile indicates they work for the company and didn't properly disclose it), maybe there are other similar posts from that user (or other suspicious looking users) that are giving you the impression that you're looking at an ad campaign, rather than a real person's question.  This will all be very helpful for a mod in determining if the post is actually spam.

Using a custom mod flag will also help a mod determine if you're flagging 1) in good faith and 2) with a proper understanding of the rules.  If you flag a post, and use a custom flag to say, "this is spam because it's linking to another website" and the post doesn't have any signs of spam other than a link to the website, your flag is likely getting declined, because you're demonstrating a lack of understanding of what spam is. But if you flag the post saying, "I think this person is affiliated with the product because of XXX," or "I think that this person isn't asking in good faith, and that this is actually spam, because all of their posts seem to find some weird way of putting a link to some product in there even though it doesn't make sense for the question," your flag almost certainly will be marked as helpful *even if further investigation shows that the posts aren't spam*.  If you are clearly flagging in good faith, because you *suspect* wrongdoing, but can't confirm or deny it without private information available to mods, they'll be happy for the flag and will mark it as helpful to encourage you to continue casting such flags.

Use the actual spam flag for spam that's blatant.  Spam that isn't even *trying* to be a real question, or an answer to the question it's posted under, and that is obvious *at a glance* that it's only an advertisement.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroturfing

Comment: @Servy I was exactly in the same dilemma as you explained, when I was stumbling on this question. Your analysis and answer sounds perfect where you have concluded to handlewith a _custom mod flag_. Thanks a ton for the beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 21):

I wasn't the moderator that handled the flag, but I agree with the outcome. It should have been declined.

That post is not spam. It is a genuine, good-faith effort to learn how to put a price on work they did. It is off-topic, yes, but not spam. The poster's only mistake was to not understand what is on topic for Stack Overflow.

The post makes no attempt to promote their work. There are no links to their project; there is a screenshot without a product name, and links to Booking.com pages that are just example searches. None of those links have affiliate information and there is no obvious pattern in the returned results to suggest this is a subversive method of trying to get a specific property on Booking.com some more exposure.

As such, your flag was declined correctly.

Comment: Points taken !!! Now, if `flag being declined` by the lawmakers is justified why was the post _put on hold as off-topic_ by the community users (5 votes) and in no time **deleted** by the _Subject Matter Experts_ (3 votes). Are we out of sync?

Comment: @DebanjanB: the flag was declined because it was *not spam*. Posts can be put on hold and even deleted for different reasons. We do not mark spam flags as accepted just because a post might be off topic or end up deleted community vote or automated process. Spam flags can carry a heavy penalty for the author of a post, we prefer to err on the side of caution. And how would you, as a flagger, learn when your flags were applied correctly without feedback?

Comment: @pnuts: with that attitude, most of Stack Overflow can be flagged. No, asking how to price work as a professional developer does not need to be looked at with that much suspicion. We don't need to be that paranoid to detect genuine attempts at pulling off stealthy spam.

Comment: I agree it is not spam.  To be even more welcoming, the question should have been kept around long enough for the OP to get a meta-pseudo-answer in comments, such as: "this sounds like a legal business question, not a programming question"; "thats off topic here; it would be better to ask on a freelancer site"; "I doubt our opinions mean anything.  You should ask about what evidence you'll need in a payment dispute on law.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @Paul: the post was visible and available for such comments for 90 minutes. While unfortunate that it didn't receive such comments, you can't expect Selenium experts to have the time or ready knowledge to spend on redirecting the author of a wildly off-topic question to better resources.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't.  I suspect comments like that come from bored generalists. Anyway I can see the question might be annoying to experts subscribed to any kind of push notification... (but does SO even do that;  I know I wouldn't dare subscribe to a question feed after my Google+ experience)

Comment: @Paul: searches and tag pages have RSS feeds you can use. I use RSS feeds for bountied posts in certain tags, all posts in other more rarely-used tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Honestly I had no idea about _Spam flags can carry a heavy penalty for the author of a post_. However your answer and the follow-up comments/questions/answers are worth for a better understanding on how things work. Thanks again !!!

Comment: @Paul (1) The close reason suffices. If anyone don't think so, they're free to leave a custom comment. (2) Deleted questions can be undeleted, if they're improved.

Answer (score 6):

That's definitely an opinion-based question that has no place on Stack Overflow, but I wouldn't call it spam. The OP is not asking people to go to their site (the links all go to a 3rd-party site), or buy anything, they're just asking for opinions on *how much would you charge* for a similar product. It can be difficult to infer intentions, but I'd give them the benefit of the doubt and guess that this is just a terribly off-topic question, rather than an attempt at spam.